# lex/yacc: why do lexers have to include a parser's header file?

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to learn a little more about compiler construction, so I've been toying with flexc++ and bisonc++; for this question I'll refer to flex/bison however.

In bison, one uses the `%token` declaration to define token names, for example

```
%token INTEGER
%token VARIABLE
```

and so forth. When bison is used on the grammar specification file, a header file `y.tab.h` is generated which has some define directives for each token:

```
#define INTEGER 258
#define VARIABLE 259
```

Finally, the lexer includes the header file `y.tab.h` by returning the right code for each token:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

[a-z]   { 
            // some code
            return VARIABLE;
        }

[1-9][0-9]* {
            // some code
            return INTEGER;
        }
```

So the parser defines the tokens, then the lexer has to use that information to know which integer codes to return for each token.

**Is this not totally bizarre?** Normally, the compiler pipeline goes lexer -> parser -> code generator. Why on earth should the lexer have to include information from the parser? The lexer should define the tokens, then flex creates a header file with all the integer codes. The parser then includes that header file. These dependencies would reflect the usual order of the compiler pipeline. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many things, it's just a historical accident. It certainly would have been possible for the token declarations to have been produced by `lex` (but see below). Or it would have been possible to force the user to write their own declarations.

It is more convenient for `yacc`/`bison` to produce the token numberings, though, because:

- The terminals need to be parsed by `yacc` because they are explicit elements in the grammar productions. In `lex`, on the other hand, they are part of the unparsed actions and `lex` can generate code without any explicit knowledge about token values; and
- `yacc` (and `bison`) produce parse tables which are indexed by terminal and non-terminal numbers; the logic of the tables require that terminals and non-terminals have distinct codes. `lex` has no way of knowing what the non-terminals are, so it can't generate appropriate codes.

The second argument is a bit weak, because in practice `bison`-generated parsers renumber token ids to fit them into the id-numbering scheme. Even so, this is only possible if `bison` is in charge of the actual numbers. (The reason for the renumbering is to make the id value contiguous; by another historical accident, it's normal to reserve codes 0 through 255 for single-character tokens, and 0 for EOF; however, not all the 8-bit codes are actually used by most scanners.)

Comment: Alright, I buy it but that doesn't mean I have to like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the lexer, the tokens are only present in the return value: they are part of the target language (ie. C++), and lex itself knows nothing about them.

In the parser, on the other hand, tokens are part of the definition language: you write them in the actual parser definition, and not just in the target language. So yacc has to know about these tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the phases is not necessarily reflected in the architecture of the compiler. The scanner is the first phase and the parser the second, so in a sense data flows from the scanner to the parser, but in a typical Bison/Flex-generated compiler it is the parser that controls everything, and it is the parser that calls the lexer as a helper subroutine when it needs a new token as input in the parsing process.